# Using multiple Google Analytics accounts in the same domain

Tags: google-analytics

We own one single domain where we host several customers. Example:

- `domain.com` (our welcome and registration site)
- `domain.com/customer1` (1st customer)
- `domain.com/customer2` (2nd customer)
- `domain.com/customer3` (3rd customer)

Is it possible to have multiple Google Analytics accounts, so that the analytics are targeted depending on the url?

- `domain.com` (our own **GA** code)
- `domain.com/customer1/*` (1st customer's **GA** code)
- `domain.com/customer2/*` (2nd customer's **GA** code)
- `domain.com/customer3/*` (3rd customer's **GA** code)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There is no restriction on this from Google Analytics, but whether you can do it is going to depend on how you are including GA tracking on your site. Do you use GTM?

Comment: @Reve i use gtag, but i dont see any examples on how to add more ids, unless I just repeat the js include.

Answer (score 1):

absolutely. It is even possible:

- domain.com (our own GA code)
- domain.com/customer1/* (our own GA code, 1st customer's GA code)
- domain.com/customer2/* (our own GA code, 2nd customer's GA code)
- domain.com/customer3/* (our own GA code, 3rd customer's GA code, GA code of an affiliate of 3rd customer)

You don't said in your question, that you use GTM instead of GA. With GA you can easily add multiple IDs, like [here](https://www.optimizesmart.com/using-multiple-trackers-for-cross-domain-tracking-in-universal-analytics/)

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-12345-12', 'auto'); 
ga('create', 'UA-1244524-22';, 'auto',{'name': 'WebProperty2'}); 
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('WebProperty2.send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

But with GTM you can indeed add multiple GTM containers, but not multiple dataLayers, as noted [here](https://www.clickinsight.ca/blog/run-multiple-gtm-containers).

Comment: Is there any way to send the analytics info to different ids with the same included js? Example of one id: `<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X');
</script>`

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: I can definitely switch to GA, but in your example i only see 1 setAccount value, to add a second one should I just add a new push call with the other account id ?